# Chrome tries to maintain scroll position after a 302 redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've noticed that Chrome will try to maintain the scroll position after a 302 redirect.

For example, given a page like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Please wait...</p>
    <script>setTimeout(function() { window.reload(true); }, 1000)</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If, on reloading, the server returns an HTTP 302 redirect to a page with an anchor:

```
Location: /some-other-page.html#some-anchor
```

The browser will correctly scroll down to the anchor, but once the page loads, Chrome will scroll up to the top of the page. I believe this is because it is trying to maintain the scroll position (in the same way it does, for example, when using the back/forward buttons).

Note: this *only* appears to happen with an HTTP redirect; changing the JavaScript in the original page to:

```
window.location.href = "/some-other-page.html#some-anchor"
```

Works as expected (Chrome scrolls to the anchor and then stays there).

What's going on here? Is there any way to avoid this behavior (ie, so I can safely use anchors with redirects)?

(note: I realize that the page-reload-to-redirect is a bit weird, and I've been able to work around the issue with my application… but I'd like to know what's going on to avoid this issue in the future)